# Why do I have access to a variable outside of a function but not within?

Tags: php

I have a bunch of HTML and PHP code and in the template file it works fine but I'm trying to put it in a PHP function and now when I run the page I get the error `Undefined variable: variableName`

Here's some code:

```
function testFunction()
{
    foreach ($variableName as $variable):
        echo 'tasf';
    endforeach;
}
```

Inside that function `$variableName` cannot be found but if I move it outside the function it can be found just fine. I'm doing this within a symfony php template file if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple issue of **variable scope**. If that variable is defined outside the function then either you need to pass it there or declare it global

[See Manual Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Hmm.. In other languages (like C# or Java) isn't it the case that if you can access a variable in a file outside a function you can also access it within the function? This concept is new to me but then again so is PHP.

Comment: @JohnSmith Every programming language has concept of Variable Scope. However there can be slight differences from one to another.

Comment: Okay good to know thanks. Yeah the second code example in the linked manual explains it. Hmm not sure how I feel about it but that's fine.

Comment: @JohnSmith If you still have any confusion you can add that to your question and we would gladly like to explain that :)

Answer (score 3):

[PHP Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

```
$str = 'Hello World';
echo $str; // works fine

function foo($bar){
    echo $bar; // passed as function argument. works fine
}

foo($str);

function bar(){
    global $str;
    echo $str; // passed from global. works fine
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Function scope means that variables referenced inside a function, must be declared within it, or passed...

```
function testFunction($variableName)
{
    foreach ($variableName as $variable):
        echo 'tasf';
    endforeach;
}
```

Here's [a link to the PHP manual on Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Under no circumstances should you resort to using `global` variables. There is always a better way, and doing so is considered poor practice. It makes your code difficult to follow as it means anyone else may have to read *all* of it in order to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword to make this happen.

`global` should be used sparingly however, and can have unintended side effects.